# Can't query by Date in appengine - org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date is not a supported property type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Trying to run a query using JDO syntax on Google's Java App Engine:

```
query.setFilter("dateField < dateParam");
query.declareParameters("java.util.Date dateParam");
List<...> results = (List<...>) query.execute(maxDate);
```

But I get the following error `org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date is not a supported property type`:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument
     NestedThrowables:
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dateField: org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date is not a supported property type.
         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:488)
         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:321)
```

But I'm not passing `org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date`, I'm passing a `java.util.Date`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my assumption that I was passing a `java.util.Date` was wrong. I was actually getting `maxDate` from another object that I had retrieved from the datastore. Yes that object was a java.util.Date, but under the bonnet, app engine swaps it for the `org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date` sub-type.

Therefore, a simple work-around is to make sure you just use a fresh Date object first:

```
if (maxDate instanceof org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date) {
    maxDate = new Date(((org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date) maxDate).getTime());
}

query.setFilter("dateField < dateParam");
query.declareParameters("java.util.Date dateParam");
List<...> results = (List<...>) query.execute(maxDate);
```